# Conflict support.v4.app.Fragment vs app.Fragment when using DatePickerDialog

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, android-support-library, datepickerdialog

I don't really understand what's going on with the support.v4 library but anyway. I have a Fragment that I implemented to be opened when clicking an item in the navigation drawer (default implementation from android studio). In this fragment, i'd like to open a datePickerDialog but I can't find the solution for it to work. Here is my fragment with the datePicker:

```
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Calendar;

public class SearchFragment extends Fragment {

private ListView listView;
private CustomAdapter activityAdapter;
private Button filterButton;

public SearchFragment(){}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search, container, false);

    activityAdapter = new CustomAdapter(getActivity());

    listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lvActivity);
    listView.setAdapter(activityAdapter);
    activityAdapter.loadObjects();
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
            String activity = activityAdapter.getItem(position).get("activity").toString();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), activity, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    filterButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.bFilter);

    return rootView;
}

public void showDatePickerDialog(View v) {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
}

public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
        implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        // Do something with the date chosen by the user
    }
}
```

}

My problem is in this line : newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");

I've seen there is a compatibility problem if the activity doesn't extend Fragment but my activity is already extending ActionBarActivity. What should I do ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you have not.  you have the wrong import here

```
  import android.app.DialogFragment;
```

change it to use the support library

Comment: That doesn't seem to change anything.

Comment: did you changed the DialogFragment import to use the support library (just double checking)

Comment: Yes, I change for this line : import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;

Comment: it strange that you get the same error on the same line. Can you try to clean up your environment and build it again?

Comment: I am getting confusing. Can you tell me where those two lines `public void showDatePickerDialog(View v) {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
}` are placed? You are using `getSupportFragmentManager()` that is not available for the fragment but for the activity,

Comment: I'm using it in my class SearchFragment which is called when I click on an item in the navigation drawer. Am I wrong ?

Comment: can you change getSupportFragmentManager in getFragmentManager?

Comment: That's "working". I can launch the app. Why is that ? However the app crash claiming there is no such method:java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: showDatePickerDialog This is the method containing the getFragmentManager.

Comment: I've found the solution. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Change 
`import android.app.DialogFragment;`

to

```
android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment
```

This will import the DialogFragment class from the support package